# bootstrap 4 beta carousel dark overlay

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making use of the [carousel control](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) of bootstrap v4.0.0-beta but I can't seem to get a dark transparent overlay over the images to create a nice contrast between the image a and the text.

Anyway have any ideas.

I've tried wrapper div classed for example:

```
.dark-overlay{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

And then with the above-mentioned class wrap the image tags with:

```
<div class="dark-overlay">
  <img class="first-slide" src="#" alt="First slide">
</div>
```

I saw some solutions where the image is set as a background onto the slide, but I want to keep the carousel dynamic as I want to swop images out. Thus setting it as a background image is maybe not the best solution.

Any help on how this can be solved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just found a solution now.

This is the original control copied from the documentation:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simply add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.carousel-item:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You're the man! How did you come up with the properties: content, display, position, top, bottom, left, and right though? I would've never assumed to trying anything beyond setting the background in :after.

Comment: You can also use a gradient for your background, to only have some dark at the bottom.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!

Answer (score -1):

Solution for your code will be to set 'position' to 'relative' for your 'dark-overlay' div and all css you wrote for this element move to selector '.dark-overlayer:after' and add 'display: block' to them, example:

```
.dark-overlay {
    position: relative;
}
.dark-overlay:after {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 250px;
}
```